# Where do I find these gimp "paint brushes"

Tags: gimp

I have a co-worker that makes these great gimp diagrams for system design stuff.  I would like to be able to make these sort of diagrams also.  I would ask my co-worker but he is not very friendly or helpful. But he makes great diagrams like this ...[image]

I believe he is using "paint brushes" that he downloaded from somewhere.  I have tried web searches for "gimp paint brushes for system design" and all I can find is stuff that can only assume is used for making album covers for Marilyn Manson.  can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: So why the down votes?  Is this the wrong forum? I a lot of gimp questions on SO so I do not believe this is an inappropriate question for SO.  Has this question already been answered? If so please post a link to it.

Comment: The appropriate form for this question would be at graphicdesign.stackexchange.com . Although sometimes a design question is answered here, only programing (like in questions regarding the creation of GIMP scripts and plug-ins) are on topic here.